# Best cards to hit a straight

Tags: odds

Which cards have the best chance of making a straight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might be hard to follow but which cards will make the most straights. The sweet spot is 45 to TJ. It is combination of steeling below and participating above.  34 and JQ drop off 30%.  One gappers from 4 to J have better odds than 34 and JQ.  I did this brute force running all the combinations - 2,118,760.  The table does not exclude flushes.

I am writing a poker calculator and odds were jumping around so I thought there was an error so I traced it down.  The pattern pretty much indicates to me the calculator is correct.  All the 0 below the x is bock / steal on the straight below.  Ace high has more straights as there is no block above.

[image: StraightOdds]